# Django Forms BoundField - Output when iterating over ChoiceField has no id tag

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I'm making a html form using Django Forms. I use [BoundFields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#more-granular-output) because my form layout has some special things in it.

I have a ChoicesField with a RadioSelect widget in my form. I iterate manually over the the choices because I want to put an img inside the `<li>`:

```
<ul>
    {% for country in form.country %}
        <li>
            <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}country_icons/country_{{ country.value }}.png">
            {{ country }}
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

But now the output doesn't include id tags on the input elements:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <img src="/media/country_icons/country_nl.png">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" value="nl" name="country" checked="checked">
            Netherlands
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="/media/country_icons/country_de.png">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" value="de" name="country">
            Germany
        </label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

While, when I wouldn't iterate over the options and just output the field:

```
{{ form.country }}
```

will output:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <label for="id_country_0">
            <input id="id_country_0" type="radio" value="nl" name="country" checked="checked">
            Netherlands
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="id_country_1">
            <input id="id_country_1" type="radio" value="de" name="country">
            Germany
        </label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

So my problem is that the id field is not there when I manually iterate over the choices. This makes inconsistency in my css/javascript selectors.

So my question is, is there some way to include the id-tag anyway?
Is this behaviour intended anyway? Or might this be a bug? Anyone run into a similar kind of issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why it works like that. My guess would be that those id's are created by an iterator created by the forms api. A single country is not aware of the iterator (it *could* appear in the template without appearing within a for loop), therefor there's no way of creating the id.

To answer your other question - Yes you could build the inputs yourself to include the id's.

something like -

```
{% for country in form.country %}
    <li>
        <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}country_icons/country_{{ country.value }}.png">
        <label for="id_country_{{ forloop.counter0 }}">
            <input id="id_country_{{ forloop.counter0 }}" type="radio" value="{{ country.value }}" name={{ country }}>
        </label>
        {{ country.name }}
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Have a look at the docs on [template for loops](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#for)